# How to compare 3 column

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

I have my excel file as below :

[image: T1]

I wish to count how many Fruit which the Ship status is not Closed. It will be something like this:

[image: T2]

Currently I only have my formula `=COUNTIFS(B2:B10,G1,A2:A10,F2)` is to count the all data including the status with closed, is there any possible to exclude the Closed status?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add the last column:

```
=COUNTIFS(B2:B10,G1,A2:A10,F2,C2:C10,"<>Closed")
```

Comment: Hi, but this will ignore the blank cell, is there any possibility to count the blank cell as well?

Answer (score 0):

As previously mentioned, the

```
=COUNTIFS(B2:B10,G1,A2:A10,F2,C2:C10,"<>Closed")
```

should work. With respect to your blank cell comment, there may be a more complicated way to do this but I would simply replace the blanks with an "x" or a "N/A" or some other placeholder so the function will count it.

In general the fact that excel ignores blanks is a lifesaver, so I would recommend this placeholder method in lieu of changing any settings.

Pressing ALT then "h" then "f" then "d" then "r" will bring up find and replace where you can make this substitution after highlighting your selection with the blanks you want counted.